# Generating session with id and password

Tags: session-management

Most web apps generate a long hex number and use it as a sessionid.

My idea is to create an ID which is auto-incrementing for each generated session and assign it a random secure string (a password). Why? It is easier to look up on an int index, it is faster to update and it occupies less space.

Does this present any security risks? (I ask exclusively for the (int)id-password style; for the string generator I am pretty sure I nailed it)

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding you, you want a session cookie with a value like `123=d9f858e302de247cc86bed48b9eebbde`, then server-side you look up session id 123 and check that the random string matches?

Comment: @AndrolGenhald Yes.

Comment: My initial thoughts are that you disclose the number of sessions you've had, and you'd have to be careful to make the random string comparison constant time, but it _seems_ like it would be ok. I'm not convinced of the benefit though, it would be a good idea to do some performance tests. If you're storing sessions in sql, is an index on a 16 byte binary field really that bad?